# Is it possible for separately initialized string variables to overlap?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

If I initialize several string(character array) variables in the following ways:

```
const char* myString1 = "string content 1";
const char* myString2 = "string content 2";
```

Since `const char*` is simply a pointer a specific `char` object, it does not contain any size or range information of the character array it is pointing to.

So, is it possible for two string literals to overlap each other? (The newly allocated overlap the old one)

By overlap, I mean the following behaviour;

```
// Continue from the code block above
std::cout << myString1 << std::endl;
std::cout << myString2 << std::endl;
```

It outputs

```
string costring content 2
string content 2
```

So the start of `myString2` is somewhere in the middle of `myString1`. Because `const char*` does not "protect"("possess") a range of memory locations but only that one it points to, I do not see how C++ can prevent other string literals from "landing" on the memory locations of the older ones.

How does C++/compiler avoid such problem?

If I change `const char*` to `const char[]`, is it still the same?

Comment: Why would the compiler make such an elementary mistake ? It perfectly knows the string lengths and allocates accordingly. As a null byte is appended, the length information needs not be stored in the executable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But what if it is `int*` or any other array that does not have a clear null byte at the end.

Comment: How would you _detect inside your program_ that these variables overlap? What is the observable behavior?

Comment: Then the application must store the length it knows or query it with sizeof. The compiler will supply the correct value.

Comment: A better example might be `const char* x = "string content 1"; const char* y = "content 1";`. And, yes, those two can overlap. And, no, it's not a problem. <g>

Comment: The question is about `const char*` and string literals. Other arrays don't have the analogues of string literals. It would depend on how you initialize them. `int a[5];` will have space for `5` elements. `int* a = new int[10]` will have space for `10` elements, with dynamic storage duration. `int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` will also have space for `5` elements.

Comment: @yeputons -- if two string literals overlap, then some of their characters will be at the same address. That's easy to check.

Comment: The title is a bit off. We know the pointers themselves can't overlap and what they point at can (because they can point at different locations in the same string), but the point of the question is "Can string literals overlap?" I think changing the title to suit would make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, string literals are allowed to overlap in general. From [lex.string#9](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#9)

> ... **Whether all string-literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects)** and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object **is unspecified**.

So it's up to the compiler to make a decision as to whether any string literals overlap in memory. You can write a program to check whether the string literals overlap, but since it's unspecified whether this happens, you may get different results every time you run the program.

Comment: Um, it's easy to check. `const char *x = "ab"; const char* y = "b"; if (x + 1 == y) std::cout << "strings overlap\n";`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Running that same program multiple times could lead to different results though, right? I'll edit the answer a bit to clarify.

Comment: I don't think this answer applies in this case, since the two strings in the example are distinct, i.e. none of them are a suffix of the other.

Comment: @cigien -- **running** the same program multiple times would, I expect, always produce the same result. **Recompiling** it, with the same or a different compiler, might change the behavior.

Comment: @Fullfungo -- that depends on whether you emphasize the code in the question or the words.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right, I would expect that as well, but it's not guaranteed to give the same result. It would be conforming for the program to behave differently on different runs. *Why* a compiler might produce such a program, I don't know, but I think it would be allowed.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, they asked two questions "If I initialize several `const char*` variables in the following ways:" and "So, is it possible for two string literals to overlap each other?", so I would imagine they are more interested in the specific question rather then the general case (which wouldn't cause any problems, that they described).

Comment: @cigien: The only realistic case in which I could see such a difference between runs is when the program is made up of several libraries loaded at runtime, where the two strings come from different libraries. In that case I could imagine that the exact load order might matter.

Answer (score 4):

A string is required to end with a null character having a value of 0, and can't have such a character in the middle.  So the only case where this is even possible is when two strings are equal from the start of one to the end of both.  That is not the case in the example you gave, so those two particular strings would never overlap.

Edit: sorry, I didn't mean to mislead anybody.  It's actually easy to put a null character in the middle of a string with `\0`.  But most string handling functions, particularly those in the standard library, will treat that as the end of a string - so your strings will get truncated.  Not very practical.  Because of that the compiler won't try to construct such a string unless you explicitly ask it to.

Comment: Does it means `"asd\0asd"` is a invalid string literal? I always thought there is no problem with having additional `\0` in middle.

Comment: I just read standard, but I cannot find any limit on `\0` in middle of string literal. it just specify that it always end with `\0`.

Comment: @Afshin https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape suggest that `\0` is actually a valid character to use in a string literal.

Comment: Afshin is correct, but that doesn't matter for the assumption in the question. String folding is a compiler feature, and doesn't depend on C library functions.

Comment: @MSalters but the point I was making in my answer is that string folding can only occur if the end of one string corresponds to a zero in the other one, because that's how both C and C++ express string literals.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows the size of each string, because it can "see" it in your code.

Additionally, they are not allocated the same way, that you would allocate them at run-time. Instead, if the strings are constant and defined globally, they are most likely located in the `.text` section of the object file, not on the heap.

And since the compiler knows the size of a constant string at compile-time, it can simply put its value in the free space of the `.text` section. The specifics depend on the compiler you use, but be assured the people who wrote are smart enough to avoid this issue.

If you define these strings inside some function instead, the compiler can choose between the first option and allocating space on the stack.

As for the `const char[]`, most compilers will treat it the same way as `const char*`.

Comment: Note that the .text section is a common implementation detail. As is the heap.

Comment: @user4581301 Indeed, this is true, I only provided a typical realistic case. The actual way it works depends on the compiler and the OS that are used.

Comment: Re: `const char[]`, yes, maybe, the `const` matters. But `char x[] = "ab"; char y[] = "ab";` defines two different arrays, each of 3 `char`.

Comment: You know, I think we've both been looking in the wrong direction. The question isn't about how the literals are being stored in the program file, it's how the strings are being presented in the program.

Comment: @user4581301 they are presented the same way they are written in the source code, there is no mystery here.

Comment: It's a hell of a lot more efficient if they are, but they do not have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Two string literals will not likely overlap unless they are the same. In that case though the pointers will be pointing to the same thing. (This isn't guaranteed by the standard though, but I believe any modern compiler should make this happen.)

```
const char *a = "Hello there."
const char *b = "Hello there."

cout << (a == b);
// prints "1" which means they point to the same thing
```

The `const char *` can share a string though.

```
const char *a = "Hello there.";
const char *b = a + 6;

cout << a;
// prints "Hello there."
cout << b;
// prints "there."
```

I think to answer your second question an explanation of c-style strings is useful.

A `const char *` is just a pointer to a string of characters. The const means that the characters themselves are immutable. (They are stored as part of the executable itself and you wouldn't want your program to change itself like this. You can use the `strings` command on unix to see all the strings in an executable easily i.e. `strings a.out`. You will see many more strings than what you coded as many exist as part of the standard library other required things for an executable.)

So how does it know to just print the string and then stop at the end? Well a c-style string is required to end with a null byte (`\0`). The complier implicitly puts it there when you declare a string. So `"string content 1"` is actually `"string content 1\0"`.

```
const char *a = "Hello\0 there.";

cout << a;
// prints "Hello"
```

For the most part `const char *a` and `const char a[]` are the same.

```
// These are valid and equivalent
const char *a = "Hello";
const char b[] = "there."


// This is valid
const char *c = b + 3; // *c = "re."
// This, however, is not valid
const char d[] = b + 3;
```